# cucumber, rails and session variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, session-variables

I'm implementing a two step login. In the first step the user has to enter his email+password. If correct then a random string is generated, stored in the session and sent to the account holder's mobile phone.

I wonder how to access the session variable from within my step definitions or how to otherwise capture the random string so that I can use fill it in the form and so test the whole login as the user would use it. The string is not stored in the model because it's only temporary.

Thanks,
Corin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stub the token generator to return a fixed string.

Comment: That would work, but I found it's better to stub the SMSGateway so I can also check the whole message sent out. Thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by stubbing the SMSGateway. My code in features/env.rb:

```
require 'cucumber/rspec/doubles'

...

Before do |scenario|
  @smsgateway_sent_text_messages = []
  SMSGateway.stub(:send_text_message) do |message, phone_number|
    @smsgateway_sent_text_messages << {
      :phone_number => phone_number,
      :message => message,
    }
  end
end
```